# If $B \subseteq A$ and $f:A\overset{1-1}\longrightarrow B$ then $A \supseteq B \supseteq f^1(A) \supseteq f^1 (B) \supseteq f^2(A) \supseteq...$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

In *The Foundations of Mathematics* by Kenneth Kunen, the following Lemma is posited:

If $B \subseteq A$ and $f:A\overset{1-1}\longrightarrow B$ then $A \approx B$

In the course of proving this statement, the author makes the intermediary claim:

> $A \supseteq B \supseteq f^1(A) \supseteq f^1 (B) \supseteq f^2(A) \supseteq f^2(B) \supseteq...$

The aim of this question is to prove **this** above claim.

The only other information necessary is the explanation of the notation $f^n$...

Kunen alludes to the creation of a recursive function, which I have attempted to formalize below:

$$F(n): \begin{cases} 
I_A \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{if } n=0 \\
f \circ (F\upharpoonright n) (n-1) \quad \quad \ \text {if } 1\leq n \lt \omega
\end{cases}$$

where $f$ is the aforementioned  $f:A\overset{1-1}\longrightarrow B$.

For notational convenience, for all $0 \leq n \lt \omega$, $F(n)$ will be written as $f^n$.

For example, $F(0)=f^0$, $F(1)=f^1$, etc.

And from our rule: $f^0 = I_A$, $f^1=f\circ f^0$, $f^2=f\circ f^1$, $f^3=f\circ f^2$, etc.

---

**Proving The Claim** If $B \subseteq A$ and $f:A\overset{1-1}\longrightarrow B$ then $A \supseteq B \supseteq f^1(A) \supseteq f^1 (B) \supseteq f^2(A) \supseteq f^2(B) \supseteq...$

I believe the above statement amounts to proving the following two statements:

Statement 1. $\forall n \in \omega\big( f^n(B) \subseteq f^n(A)\big)$

Statement 2. $\forall n \in \omega\big( f^{n+1}(A) \subseteq f^n(B)\big)$

Also, I think it is necessary to demonstrate that $\forall n \in \omega \big(f^n(A) \subseteq A \land f^n(B) \subseteq A \big)$. Recognizing that $f$ could be rewritten as $f:A\overset{1-1}\longrightarrow A$ (because $B \subseteq A$), this is straightforward so **will not be proven**.

---

*Proof of Statement 1*:

**Base Case $n=0$**: $f^0(B)\subseteq f^0(A)$

$f^0 = I_A$, $I_A(B)=B, I_A(A)=A$, $B \subseteq A$

**Assume for $n$**: $f^n(B) \subseteq f^n(A)$

**Prove for $n+1$**: $f^{n+1}(B) \subseteq f^{n+1}(A)$

Note that $f^{n+1}(B) = f \circ f^n (B)$ and $f^{n+1}(A) = f \circ f^n (A)$

By definition of function composition:

$f \circ f^n (B)=f\big(f^n (B)\big)$ and $f \circ f^n (A)=f\big(f^n (A)\big)$

Let $y$ be an arbitrary element in $f\big(f^n (B)\big)$.

Therefore, there is an $x \in f^n (B)$ such that $f(x)=y$.

By assumption, $f^n(B) \subseteq f^n(A)$, which means that $x \in f^n(A)$.

But then $f(x) \in f\big(f^n(A)\big)$...so $y\in f\big(f^n(A)\big) \quad \square$

---

*Proof of Statement 2* - A very similar argument

**Base Case $n=0$**: $f^1(A) \subseteq f^0(B)$

$f^1(A)=f(A)$ and $f^0(B)=B$. By the definition of $f$, $f(A) \subseteq B$

**Assume for $n$**:  $f^n+1(A) \subseteq f^n(B)$

**Prove for $n+1$**: $f^{n+2}(A) \subseteq f^{n+1}(B)$

$f^{n+2}(A)=f\big(f^{n+1}(A)\big)$ and $f^{n+1}(B)=f\big(f^n(B)\big)$

Let $y$ be an arbitrary element in $f\big(f^{n+1}(A)\big)$.

Therefore, there is an $x \in f^{n+1}(A)$ such that $f(x)=y$.

By assumption, $f^n+1(A) \subseteq f^n(B)$, which means $x \in f^n(B)$.

But then $f(x) \in f\big(f^n(B)\big)$...so $y\in f\big(f^n(B)\big) \quad \square$

Comment: Yes, it’s correct. You do not, however, have to demonstrate that $f^n[A]$ and $f^n[B]$ are subsets of $A$ for each $n\in\omega$; the fact that $f$ is a subset of $A\times A$ as well as of $A\times B$ is not relevant.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for going through the arduous task of reading this! As for your comment, I have a quick question. I thought that demonstrating $f^n[A] \subseteq A$ would be necessary in order to ensure that a statement like $f(f^n[A])$ was "defined". I'm still pretty inexperienced, but I figured that if, INSTEAD, $A \subset f^n[A]$, then a statement like $f(f^n[A])$ would basically be "bad syntax" because there are objects in $f^n[A]$ that $f$ will not map anywhere. Also, it seems like demonstrating $f^n[A] \subseteq A$ is actually required in order to define my recursive function.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you were worried about; I had misunderstood your concern. Technically you are correct, and at this stage it’s good that you recognized it; in practice it’s sufficiently obvious that it needn’t actually be mentioned (which is why I didn’t realize what you were getting at). You’re most welcome.